# Using os.system and subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, shell, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have been trying to write a python script to control my Virtual machine remotely. For example I want to run a program on my VM and check if it is running. For this step I tries with Os.system and it seems it is working but for having better control I like to use subprocess, but unfortunately there was no success. I provided my code for both os.system and subprocess as follows:

```
os.system("vmrun -gu root -gp mohsen77 runProgramInGuest F:\Client\Ubuntu10464bit.vmx usr/bin/tcpreplay --intf1=eth4 /home/srastega/output.pcap")
print('PID is:' + str(os.getpid()))

args = shlex.split("vmrun -gu root -gp mohsen77 runProgramInGuest F:\Client\Ubuntu10464bit.vmx /bin/ls -l")
tcpreplay = subprocess.Popen(args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = tcpreplay.communicate()
print(out)
print('PID is:' + str(tcpreplay.pid))
```

For the second piece of code I am receiving an error:

> Error: Cannot open VM: F:\ClientUbuntu10464bit.vmx, The virtual machine cannot b
>   e found

Comment: The error message has a missing \ before the `U`.  In general, while I don't know why they're behaving differently, I'm a little suspicious of those single backslashes in a double-quoted string.  I would worry about those getting mangled.

Comment: Good comment! I've found that shlex.split output is not considering those \s in the path so if I print out the args, it will be: ['vmrun', '-gu', 'root', '-gp', 'mohsen77', 'runProgramInGuest', 'F:ClientUbuntu10464bit.vmx', '/bin/ls', '-l'] which is not we want. I have to find a solution to reserve those \s when I use split.

Comment: Problem solved by changing the line to: args = shlex.split("vmrun -gu root -gp mohsen77 runProgramInGuest F:/Client/Ubuntu10464bit.vmx /bin/ls -l")

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes in the double-quoted string may have special meaning, which could cause them to disappear.  I'm not sure why the two calls are working differently, but try either doubling the backslashes or changing to forward slashes.

(Lifted to an answer from the discussion in the comments.)